# Provide an easy way to access my accounts on other sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, navigation

I have accounts on 4 Stack Exchange sites. It would be good to have some buttons inside/next to the global index to jump to their pages.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're even asking for here.

Comment: @animuson - i am asking for a new feature (on top pane : a select/option page for switching user accounts)

Comment: I rolled back the anonymous edit that left this question untagged

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This pretty much already exists. In the top navigation bar you can click the “hamburger menu” looking like the Stack Exchange logo (right-most button) and it will list every site on the network. The ones you actually have an account on are bumped to the top and sorted by the amount of reputation you have on each of them (may be cached, as usual), though you can edit the order.

[image: Screenshot of the menu item: it shows the Current Community at the top with its corresponding Meta site. Below that, it lists Your Communities. Below that, it lists all Stack Exchange communities and a search bar.]

It doesn’t link you *directly* to your user profile on that site, but it’s easy enough to just click your user icon with the reputation and badge counts to the left of your inbox, once you’re there. If you’re on your profile, you can also quickly navigate between your other accounts via the accounts summary block in the bottom left of your profile.

Another option is to just open the notification links in a new tab / window (e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Mouse Button, or Middle Mouse Button) so you can just close it once you’ve reviewed whatever the notification was for.

Comment: `and I'm not exactly sure how the rest of them are sorted` Randomly.

Comment: It doesn't prioritize all of the sites you have an account on. Just the ones where you have over 200 reputation.

Comment: @AnnaLear: My sites are ordered by reputation all the way down through Programmers (107). The ones after that with only 101 reputation appear to be random, but still bumped up above the sites where I don't have an account.

Comment: Oh, cool. That must've changed then. I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your user profile page shows the sites where you have an account. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/193632/satish-pandey.

[image: screenshot]

You can click on one of those links, and you are taken to your user profile on that site.

Comment: This is only available when you go to user profile. Very long process to switch to another account.